# Problema números apos a virgula

Tags: vb.net

Olá eu tenho esse código em um button.

```
txtresultado.Text = Math.Round(txtsalmin.Text * 0.2, 2).ToString
```

Em que ele pega o valor do salmin.text e multiplicar poe 0,2 e aparece no txtresultado.text com no máximo 2 casas depois da virgula. E o meu problema é o seguinte, por exemplo se fazer fazer 937 * 0,2 é igual a 187,4 e isso aparece no txtresultado.text, até aqui tudo certo, mas eu gostaria que aparecesse 187,40 pois estou trabalhando com dinheiro nesse sistema e tem que aparecer as 2 casas apos a virgula.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode especificar o número de casas decimais no método ToString() da seguinte forma:

```
txtresultado.Text = Math.Round(txtsalmin.Text * 0.2, 2).ToString.("N2")
txtresultado.Text = Math.Round(txtsalmin.Text * 0.2, 2).ToString.("F2")
```

Fica aqui um pequeno exemplo

```
Imports System

Public Module modmain
   Sub Main()
       Console.WriteLine ( Math.Round(10937 * 0.2, 2).ToString())     
       Console.WriteLine ( Math.Round(10937 * 0.2, 2).ToString("N2"))   
       Console.WriteLine ( Math.Round(10937 * 0.2, 2).ToString("F2")) 
   End Sub
End Module
```

Resultado:

```
2187.4
2,187.40
2187.40
```

Comment: Entendi, não sabia dessa opção. Valeu!